# Mongodb files exceed Github recommended size

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, gitignore

I created a node project with mongodb, but when I try to push it to github, the git console says that

```
remote: warning: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: warning: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: warning: File Server/data/local.0 is 64.00 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File Server/data/project.0 is 64.00 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
```

Am I not supposed to be pushing .0 files to my git repo?
All the files in the /data/ folder are what mongo created.

Comment: Any particular reason for wanting to put these files in your repo?

Comment: Well I want to sync my database so my other collaborators have access to it

Comment: Perhaps consider using an online hosting service like modulus.io. I use them for my projects and I am yet to be disappointed (they also have a free plan).

Comment: It looks good, but do people usually just upload their databases to git?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Usually people only put code in git, never the database. [Is backing up a MySQL database in Git a good idea?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/241109/is-backing-up-a-mysql-database-in-git-a-good-idea)

Comment: Ok thanks. So I should definitely use an online database to keep my data in sync between everyone?

Answer (score 0):

You will get these warnings for files over 50MB.
Files over 100MB will be denied if an attempt is made to upload them to github.

source: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/

Comment: To answer your question more directly: the .0 extension has nothing to do with why you are seeing these warnings; filesize is the only factor here.

Comment: Right, but I just created the database though, there are only like 4 lines in a table, so if it's so big already, will it keep increasing for every new line I add, or does mongo preallocate a huge file for the database?

Comment: @rasen58 [Yes it does](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#faq-disk-size), and there's also journalling data which is huge in itself.